# React using props in an IF ELSE statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to use React props as the condition in an IF ELSE statement?

i.e.

```
export default function MenuItem(props) {
        if(${props.type == "extra"){
            // Do this
        }
        return (
                <div className={styles.item}>
                        <h3 className={styles.title}>{props.name}</h3>
                        <span className={styles.price}>{props.price}</span>
                        <p className={styles.description}>{props.desc}</p>
                </div>
        );  
}
```

And an example of the component in question

```
<MenuItem name="Product Name" price="£0" desc="Description goes here..." type="extra" />
```

Comment: If you look in the web console, you should see a syntax error pointing to that `if` statement. `if(${` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `props` parameter is just a normal parameter, you don't have to wrap it in `${}` to use it:

```
if (props.type === "extra") {
    // Do this
}
```

(In fact, `${}` doesn't mean anything in React/JSX. It has meaning within a template literal, but that doesn't seem relevant.)

Comment: Excellent thank you I was wondering why it wouldn't work with the wrappers

Comment: Yeah I think it's because I've been using template literals all day so ended up guessing with one, initially, I tried it without the `$` and just `{}` that also didn't work

Comment: I have a second question about using module css classes within a function, original post edited

Comment: @ContainLetters - That's completely unrelated to the original question. Rather than editing it into the question, you should post a new question asking how to do that (and providing the details of whatever CSS framework you're using). :-)

Comment: Crowder I will ask a new question it will take 90 minutes however as I can only post once every so often

Comment: @ContainLetters - Well, that's just a limitation for now. But what you were asking about involves directly accessing the DOM, which you want to avoid in React. So a properly-asked question is really your best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use react props in conditional statements like below.

```
export default function MenuItem(props) {
        if(props.type === "extra"){
            // Do this
        }
        return (
                <div className={styles.item}>
                        <h3 className={styles.title}>{props.name}</h3>
                        <span className={styles.price}>{props.price}</span>
                        <p className={styles.description}>{props.desc}</p>
                </div>
        );  
}

<MenuItem name="Product Name" price="£0" desc="Description goes here..." type="extra" />
```

Answer to your 2nd Question.

Can you try the below approach?

```
if(props.type == "extra"){
 const d = document.getElementsByClassName(styles.item)
       d[0].classList.add("extra");
    }
```

Comment: I have a second question about using module css classes within a function, original post edited

Comment: Can you please help in clearing what you are referring to?

Comment: the second question is in the original post now

Answer (score 0):

If your props.type is not inside quotes or jsx you don't need ${} or {}. While debugging my personal preference is to log the variable with these things in mind what you may want to do is:

```
console.log(props.type) \\ as i said not imp but just to be sure    
if(props.type === "extra"){
           //return something this(and you have to use return)
       }

      return (
               <div className={styles.item}>
                       <h3 className={styles.title}>{props.name}</h3>
                       <span className={styles.price}>{props.price}</span>
                       <p className={styles.description}>{props.desc}</p>
               </div>
       );
```

Comment: I have a second question about using module css classes within a function, original post edited